# Timeslots application - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, timeslots

I would like to create a Ruby on Rails application similar to Doodle that would allow users to book/reserve a time interval within a certain time.

For instance, dividing an hour in 12 slots of 5 minutes and allowing users (12 users in that case) to select one slot.

That would be for my business.

As an Admin I could:

- Create/Delete/Modify users.
- Create/Delete time slots.
- Comment.

As a User I could:

- Select a slot.
- Comment.

I have some notions of RoR, HTML, CSS and JS and I was wondering if there is any kind of tutorial on the web to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty vague question so be careful with that because stack overflow will probably close it soon. There is a lot of resources on the web about getting started but personally I have to say to go to https://www.railstutorial.org/book and really just pay attention and run through it. 
It's not exactly what you are looking for but I was able to expand my first application off of this tutorial and then when you restart and make your own application you'll at least have a very good way of getting all of these things done and have the basics down. It does touch upon the user admin permissions you are looking at but in more of a twitter like application so you'd have to change a lot of things around.

If you have any more specific questions feel free to post here or contact me and I'd be happy to help